# Have nuclear physicists ever turned lead into gold?

Tags: nuclear-physics, elements

The holy grail of ancient alchemy was a process for converting lead into gold.

(Well, for some alchemists, the *true* holy grail was, in fact, the actual Holy Grail. But that's another topic entirely.)

**Have any nuclear physics experiments ever converted a measurable quantity of lead into gold?**

[This](https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/turning-lead-into-gold) popular science article claims that in "the 1970s", Glenn Seaborg, Walt Loveland, and Dave Morrissey performed a nuclear experiment that converted lead into gold, and then published a widely publicized "paper" about it - but annoyingly, the popular article does not actually cite the paper.

But [this](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-lead-can-be-turned-into-gold/) popular article claims that "Morrissey and colleagues" converted *bisthmuth* into gold, and explicitly says that they chose *not* to use lead. The article claims that they published the results of their work in "the March 1981 issue of Physical Review C", although annoyingly it does not link to the journal article either. The only article by David J. Morrissey that I could find in the March 1981 issue of Physical Review C was [this one](https://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.23.1044), which indeed reports that bisthmuth was the input element.

Comment: Try [Modern Nuclear Chemistry](https://books.google.com/books?id=yuxWDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Glenn Seaborg, Walt Loveland, and Dave Morrissey. Ch 12.5.5 is on Synthesis of Nuclei with A > 60. The preview on Google Books did not show the contents, but you can get the book.

Comment: Note that bismuth, unlike lead, is monoisotopic, which makes interpretation of any results much easier. Anyway, nuclear experiments of this kind are not an economic way to produce larger quantities of any element...

Comment: An interesting [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/114vo4m/alchemy_famously_sought_to_turn_lead_into_gold/) from earlier in the year indicates that lead was not the only metal/element these "proto-chemists" were interested in transmuting to gold (basically any common metal was investigated).

Comment: And [answers to this PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1530/25301) indicate it *was* done for sure in the 60s, but I didn't follow any links or references there.

Comment: @KyleKanos By "it", do you mean "transmuting from lead" or "transmuting from any common element". I already provided a reference to the latter in my question. For the former, I don't see reliable sources on that SE page. I was unable to find the paper that Owen claims to cite. Lubos's link leads to a "ThoughtCo." page that says "*It's been reported* that Glenn Seaborg ... succeeded in transmuting a minute quantity of lead (*although he may have started with bismuth* ...) into gold in 1980" - again, with no citations. This seems like a highly unreliable source.

Comment: @tparker yes, by "it" I mean the transmutation from lead. I also stated that I didn't follow any of the links. I found the reddit more interesting, in any event.

Answer (score 1):

What do you call a measurable quantity?
What is certain is that the known means of transmutation (nuclear reactors, accelerators) cannot transmute all the atoms of a target material. And it is not possible to discern the atoms to be transmuted.
At best, if you find the nuclear reactions that go well, you will get gold atoms mixed into a matrix of the starting material.
Furthermore, another difficulty among many others, as soon as you form the first gold atoms, these in turn become target atoms which will undergo transmutations.
So, completely transmuting 10 grams of natural lead into gold, no, this has never been achieved and is still not possible today.